# Python: Check mp3 file is fully downloaded

Tags: python, mp3, aac, flac

I wrote a small python script that's monitor user music library and add new files info (mp3, aac, flac) to sqllite db.

If user download music from torrents, how can i check that it is fully downloaded and is not corrupted?

Comment: To do this reliably you'd need to know the piece size from the torrent. However, you could assume the smallest block size (16 KiB) and read through your files looking for 16 KiB 0x00 bytes. This assumes that your client zeroes the file before writing it, which some seem to do.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way would be to open the torrent up and verify the hash of the file. Nobody knows if your torrent is done better than your torrent file.

https://github.com/mohanraj-r/torrentparse